# versioning on a has_and_belongs_to_many?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

Is it possible at all to have versioning for `has_and_belongs_to_many` associations?
The official documentation only briefly mentions `has_many` and `belongs_to`.
I have added papertrail on both ends of my `has_and_belongs_to_many` association, run the migrations and whenever I update the association from either end, nothing ever gets added to the version_associations table.
Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible at all to have versioning for has_and_belongs_to_many associations?

Yes. HABTM reification was added very recently (2016-04-25) in [PR 771](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/pull/771) and [released in version 5.0.0](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-2016-05-02).

> The official documentation [does not mention HABTM] ..

That's correct. We'd appreciate contributions to that documentation, thanks!

PS: Please note that associations are an experimental feature, not recommended for production systems.